# How reduce RPi boot-up time in Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I have RPi 3 Model B V1.2 with Raspbian Jessie OS.

I want to reduce boot-up time of RPi, so the board can boot-up (get desktop screen on HDMI) as fast as possible.

Currently, it is 42 sec. approx after attaching the power to the board. After 42 sec. I get the desktop screen on HDMI. It is configured to autologin.

Using - Wi-Fi, Ethernet, USBs, HDMI, Serial, I2C and Audio.

Not using - Bluetooth, Camera and LCD/TFT Display.

What type of changes I have to make? and Where?

Please let me know.

Comment: Edit in the output from `systemd-analyze time` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

it will tell you how much time do you spend in each boot service

Comment: will look into this command and will stop those more time-taking services.